# Strange error computation

Tags: poisson-distribution, error, sum

I have statistics question. I have an (astronomical) image, and I want to sum up the pixels within a square, and also get the error of this sum. I use the program DS9 (in case somebody knows it), and it does give me a sum, and an error. But the strange thing is, the error is exactly the square root of the sum. And I have no idea why this is the case. I've never such an error computation.

Does anybody know more?

Comment: What do these things you're summing consist of? Counts? measurements of some continuous quantity?

Comment: Yes, they are pixel counts. Imagine an image showing stars, and I want to sum up all pixels of the star.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise